# When “strong” is used after a number，does it refer to that exact number or an approximate number？

Tags: word-usage, word-meaning

When *strong* is used after a number，say in this sentence，

> We suffered severely and came back only eighty **strong**.

does it refer to exactly 80, or more than 80, or approximately 80 survivals?

Comment: http://www.learnersdictionary.com/definition/strong. 15b

Comment: seems to be synonymous to **as many as**

Answer (score 1):

The Free dictionary defines (Definition No.18) '[Strong](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/strong)' as":

> Having a specified number of units or members.

In this context, *'We suffered severely and came back only eighty strong.'* simply means that 80 people survived and came back (to wherever it maybe). In plain words, this simply means:

> After sheer suffering, only 80 people cam back, including me.

So the number is 80. Not more, not less.

Comment: I'm not sure I completely agree with the "not more, not less" part of this answer; it might be context-dependent. Note the example sentence in the [MW Learner's Dictionary](http://www.learnersdictionary.com/definition/strong), meaning 15b: _The army was ten thousand strong_. With a big number like that, 10,000 might well mean "approximately 10,000". It's not inconceivable that a person might say, "We came back only eighty strong" and mean, "We can back and only (about) 80 of us survived," particularly if (a) no exact headcount was available, and (b) they wanted to use this more "poetic" form.

Answer (score 0):

I always understood it to mean, say, 100,000 strong, meaning somewhat over 100,000, but certainly more than 100,000.